# TypeScript: What type do I set a value that is to be compared with a list of types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am very new to React and TypeScript so sorry about the confusing title.

I have a component that takes a prop as such:

```
<HelperText level={helperLevel} />
```

On the `HelperText` component this `level` value is compared to compared to an array, eg:

```
type Level = 'Low' | 'Med' | 'High';

interface HelperTextProps {
  level: Level;
  lowLevel: string;
  medLevel: string;
  highLevel: string;
}
```

However, I get an error on compilation:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Level'.  TS2322

I am not sure what this means or how to handle it. I do not understand the existing solutions on Google.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your error states helperLevel is of type string but to assign it to level it has to be of type Level - you can use typeguards.

Comment: Your `helperLevel` props should be the same type as `Level` which includes 'Low' | 'Med' | 'High'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the component that renders `<HelperText>` has a props named `helperLevel`. Your `helperLevel` props's type should be the same as `HelperText`'s level type.

```
interface HelperTextRenderComponentProps {
  helperLevel: Level; // Here should be Level instead of string.
  // OR
  helperLevel: HelperTextProps['level']; // When your `level` props changed in HelperText component, here will be changed as well.
}
```

---

If you are very sure that the `helperLevel`'s value is one of 'Low', 'Med' or 'High', you can use the `as` syntax. Generally this is not recommended as `helperLevel` can now be any string without type guard.

```
<HelperText level={helperLevel as Level} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to remember is that types are a Typescript concept and when it is compiled to JavaScript, all declared types are removed and there are no type runtime checks made (unless you have explicitly coded them in).

This means that at runtime, even though in your Typescript you have said that you are expecting a string with values `'Low' | 'Med' | 'High';`, technically in JavaScript world, these strings could be of any value and you will be none the wiser. Where am I going with this?

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Level'. TS2322

The reason you are getting this error is because type checking being a pre-compile implementation is trying to mitigate the example above where JavaScript will not be checking that the string is one of: `'Low' | 'Med' | 'High';`. So your job is to ensure the compiler that you have checked `helperLevel` and they will indeed be one of `'Low' | 'Med' | 'High';`.

To do this, update your html to: `<HelperText level={helperLevel as Level} />`

Answer (score -1):

If you set `HelperTextProps` like

```
type Level = 'Low' | 'Med' | 'High';

interface HelperTextProps {
  level: Level;
  lowLevel: string;
  medLevel: string;
  highLevel: string;
}
```

You only able to use `HelperText` component.

```
<HelperText level='Low' />
```

---

I usually do like

```
export enum Level {
  Low = 'Low',
  Med = 'Med',
  High = 'High'
}

interface HelperTextProps {
  level: Level;
  lowLevel: string;
  medLevel: string;
  highLevel: string;
}
```

And use

```
<HelperText level={Level.Low} />
```

Comment: Not at all. In your case `helperLevel` has type string and value 'Low'.